# How to add li element in ul as 2 columns

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to add li element dynamically as columns, like this picture

i have one li element  , and i want to append li element like this picture, one coluumn has to be have 4 li,, if element is 5. it has to add to another row, possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use CSS columns. It seems to be exactly what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ewsMh/.

```
ul {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
}
```

I think there are polyfills for [unsupported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/columns#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Slick solution, but latest browsers only and no IE :(

Comment: +1 because I think this is the solution to go for, however I just removed 2 `li`s and the columns became [3][3] elements each whereas the OP expects [4][2].

Comment: @Bazzz Yeah. As long as you ask for 2 columns, there will be 2 columns, no matter if there are 2 or 1 billion elements in the parent. Here is a polyfill for CSS columns: http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your DOM:**

```
<ul id="left"></ul>
<ul id="right"></ul>
```

**The function that adds li's (using jquery):**

```
var addLi = function($li) {
    var $uls = $('ul');
    $.each($uls, function(index, ul) {
        // If this ul has less than 5 li's
        // then add the li here
        if ($(this).find('li').length < 5) {
            $(this).append($li);
            // exit the for loop since we have placed this li
            return;  
        }
    }
};
addLi('<li>Test</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, take two `ul` with same class name and with different `ID's`. make them arranged adjacent to each other. while adding the `li` dynamically, count the additions with a `counter` variable. If the addition is more than 4 then just add to another `ul` tag(change the ID with which you are functioning).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
var liLength;
$("#btnAddLi").click(function() {
liLength=$('#yourLastUl li').length;
if(liLength>4)
    $("#CreateOneMoreUL").append("<li>Content</li>");
else
    $("#yourLastUL").append("<li>Content</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `ul` with `nth-child(odd)`, `nth-child(even)` selectors to target half of the elements and `float` them left and right accordingly.

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x9kxd/

Of course you miss the order of your `<li>` elements but at least you get a nice and simple solution for a two-column container.

**---EDIT---**

If your `<li>` elements need to change column after 4 items then you should use the `nth-child(-n+4)` selector. This way you keep the order as you want it.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QqudC/1/

*The `:nth-child()` selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.*